# POST multipart/form-data with NodeRed HTTP request

Tags: multipartform-data, node-red

I'm trying to generate a HTTP Webrequest in NodeRed that will upload a file to a website via a normal upload form. I guess i knwo how to upload a file, but i do not know how to pass the other input fieds i have to fill also.

I only found how to set http headers:

```
msg.headers["content-type"] = "multipart/form-data";
```

This is what i have so far:
[image: My current flow]

I have also tried in "the missing part" to write the FormData and send the Request manually. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

But also no luck with that. Only received an Error that FormData is unknown...

Comment: You will probably have to build the multi-part body yourself by hand in the function node and then place that in the msg.payload to the http-request node

Comment: I tried that from that example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects
but i get an ErrorMessage that FormData is uknown.

Comment: Edit the question to show exactly what you tried

Answer (score 0):

In the function node, before sending msg, set request header like this

```
msg.headers = {
               "content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
               }
```